# Scrolling to an a list item in a List in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a dropdown and when a user selects some item from it, then `scrollToItem` is called and it should scroll to that selected list item in the UI. But with the following code, it's not happening, it's just not scrolling at all. Could anybody take a look?:

```
  const scrollToItem = (e, data) => {
    if (data) {
      const { index } = data;
      listRef.current.scrollTo(0, index * 48)
    }
  };

return (
  <>
    <List ref={listRef}>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <ListItem
          key={index}
          onClick={() => setIndex(index)}
        >
          <ListItemText
            primary={item.m}
          />
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
    {* DROPDOWN COMPONENT HERE *}
  <>
)
```

Comment: You have applied `ref` on the List, you should apply on `ListItem` instead.
Also `scrollTo` takes x and y co-ordinates as params.
Is `index * 48` is the y co-ordinate?

Comment: @UtsavPatel applied to ListItem and it's not working as well. Correct, index * 48 is the y co-ordinate

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox that has your problem?

Comment: You should also check whether List is overflowing or not. There might be some other container overflowing.

Comment: @gautamits what do you mean by overflowing?

Comment: Any container will cause scroll only when its children are taking more height (or width), and overflow of container is set to auto or scroll.  I am assuming that List is not scrolling but some other parent of List might be overflowing , thus causing the scroll. Your code is assuming that List is scrolling. So you can just cross check once.